# Sending HTML by cURL on MAILGUN

Tags: html, curl, mailgun

I tried to send this by email. I tried a lot of ways and always I obteined the same thing: an error.

http://goto-21.net/campaign/htmlversion?mkt_hm=0&AdministratorID=47507&CampaignID=58&StatisticID=62&MemberID=733807&s=994508d6292a660150ccc60c3f0310d4&isDemo=0

I tried with this:

> curl -s --user 'api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0' \
>       Xhttps://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages \
>       -F from='Excited User ' \
>       -F to='foo@example.com' \
>       -F cc='bar@example.com' \
>       -F bcc='baz@example.com' \
>       -F subject='Hello' \
>       -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
>       -F html=' CODE HERE ' \

And this:

> curl -s --user 'api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0' \
>       Xhttps://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages \
>       -F from='Excited User ' \
>       -F to='foo@example.com' \
>       -F cc='bar@example.com' \
>       -F bcc='baz@example.com' \
>       -F subject='Hello' \
>       -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
>       --form-string html=' CODE HERE ' \

But it doesnt work...Always ''syntax error''

Anyone can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Syntax error? Just that? From curl or remote server? Also, can you make you examples look less unreadable, please?

Comment: an example screenshot

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img538/3032/9RfagM.png

Comment: From curl in terminal
an example screenshot
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img538/3032/9RfagM.png

I cant show you the example (it is too large) but... I simply paste the html where I wrote ''CODE HERE''


Is that wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following cURL command to send HTML emails using the command line.
Replace the uppercase parameter with your own and you're ready to send!

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR-API-KEY' https://api.mailgun.net/v2/YOURDOMAIN/messages -F from='YOU@YOURPROVIDER.COM' -F to=RECEIVER@PROVIDER.com -F subject='Hello World with HTML' -F html='<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>Hello <strong>World</strong></body></html>' -F text='Hello world'
```

What this does is send an email from an address attached to your domain to a receiver sending html  and plain text version as a fall back!

Happy mailgunning

Best,

Comment: Which key do I need, the [sending key](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#authentication-1) or the private api key for the mailgun curl cmd?

Answer (score 0):

the origin request is looks like:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <excited@samples.mailgun.org>' \
    -F to='devs@mailgun.net' \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
```

but you have a big X before https.

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0' \ 
-------> X <----- https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages \ -F from='Excited User ' \ -F to='foo@example.com' \ -F cc='bar@example.com' \ -F bcc='baz@example.com' \ -F subject='Hello' \ -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \ --form-string html=' CODE HERE ' \
```

maybe this cause an error